# cabal install --disable-prof not working?

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

To save time, I am trying to build a package (in a sandbox) with `--disable-doc --disable-prof`, but it's failing: when compiling some dependency (crypto-api), I get

```
Could not find module ‘System.Entropy’
Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package   
‘entropy-0.3.7@entro_GdlGosmsZhO5QKbUBFjD3f’?
```

Sure I have not, and I don't want to.

What's happening? (The workaround is to `--disable-doc` only.)

Comment: What are you actually typing? Are those even real options?

Comment: The problem is in one of the things you haven't told us about, and we know the things you've told us about aren't accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are a package *lower* in the dependency tree is forcing profiling builds, and then failing when the package it depends on has not been built that way.

Answer (score -1):

You used the wrong flags.

You need `--disable-profiling --disable-documentation`

Comment: Wrong. Have you actually tried `cabal install crypto-api --disable-profiling --disable-documentation`, in an empty sandbox? It will fail, with the error I mentioned. Abbreviation of flags to unique prefixes is allowed, the implemetation uses https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/Cabal/Distribution/GetOpt.hs